# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/add1] in DispatcherServlet with name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I checked my code so many times and also I read a lot of articles but wasn't able to correct my errors.My index.jsp is running fine but as i am calling my controller AddController file (on click of submit button in index.jsp) i am getting an error message: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/add1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ajit'

Here is the code: web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
         <servlet-name>ajit</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>ajit</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

ajit.servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

 <ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
 <ctx:component-scan base-package="com.ajit"></ctx:component-scan>
 
</beans>
```

AddController

```
package com.ajit;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AddController {
  
  
  @RequestMapping("/add1")
  public void add() {
      System.out.println("Hello how are you");
      
  }

}
```

Web Pages/index.jsp:

```
<%@page import="jdk.internal.misc.FileSystemOption"%>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
 <form action="add1">
    <% 
    
    System.out.println("Hello ooo");
    %>
     
    <input type="text" name="t1"/></br>
    <input type="text" name="t2"/></br>
    <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

pls, change your URL pattern as below in web.xml

```
<url-pattern>/add1</url-pattern>
```

You can also, different other methods from this source https://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet

Comment: I made the change in my web.xml but it is still not working

Comment: In index.jsp, check whether the import is happening right <%@page import="jdk.internal.misc.FileSystemOption"%>. Also, pls remove the import and sysout in index.jsp and try once more.